# Highcharts - hold relation among multiple series after grouping / approximation

Tags: javascript, grouping, highcharts

I am using an area plot - normal stacking - plotting 3 series. I have data-points of series 1 and series 2, but data-points for series 3 are based on relation: (100-(series1 + series2)). After I calculate points of 3rd series and assign it to series object, Highcharts grouping is applied to it, but relation described above does not hold after grouping. Seems like Highcharts applies grouping on one series at a time. So relationship goes away after it comes out of approximation function. How can I apply grouping so that relationship holds after coming out of approximation function in dataGrouping? Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit approximation function for 3rd series, so it will have values as you want it to have.

Depending on what do you expect to have as a 3rd series approximation you can use one of available approximations - like "average" or "sum" - or set up a custom function.

More info in API reference: [http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.dataGrouping.approximation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.dataGrouping.approximation)

Comment: How can make it work only for 3rd series. Currently my chart.series is array of : series1,series2,series3. So what I understand, approximation works on each series inside chart.series array.

Comment: @bosmku One way could be to create a single function and set it in plotOptions.series - this function should check what kind of series it is, e.g. based on some series property you are setting. Other option is to set approximation function only for the series that should have changed approximation - series3 should have added configuration object for dataGrouping with function defined in approximation property.